# android input problem

Tags: android

I have an android problem which generates a pie chart. There are two files in my project, mainActivity and drawChart. In mainActivity I put all the variables and the algorithm in. In drawChart I put the onDraw function. 
For now I want to generate some input areas. The problems are,
How should I generate the input? use XML or JAVA?
How should I pass the data we type in to the program?

Because I am a obsolutely beginner, so please teach me a little bit specifically.
Thank you very much.

Comment: you need to elaborate your question and be bit more clear. Add some of your code where you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit vague but as far as i can understand your question.

You need a TextView to take input from user and get it by its listener. Click [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) for more help